# How to create a new project and commit it in fortify ssc using REST API

Tags: rest, fortify

I am trying to create a new project in fortify using REST api and so far I have been able to create the application and version,but I am not able to add attributes to it and commit it.
Here is my code so far.
Here is my script that I am using to commit.

```
import requests

headers = {
'accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'FortifyToken MmRjODVjZjctOWE2Zi00NGQxLWFkZTAtZmE2ZjUxZmZiYmU1',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

json_data={
"requests": [
{
"uri": "http://localhost:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/6491/attributes",
"httpVerb": "PUT",
"postData": [
{
"attributeDefinitionId": 1,
"values": [
{
"guid": "High"
}
]
},
{
"guid":"DevPhase",
"attributeDefinitionId":"2",
"values": [
{
"guid":"Active"
}
]
} ,
{
"guid":"Accessibility",
"attributeDefinitionId":"3",
"values": [
{"guid":"externalpublicnetwork"}
]
},
{
"guid":"DevStrategy",
"attributeDefinitionId":"4",
"values": [
{"guid":"Internal"}
]
}
]

},

{

"uri": "http://localhost:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/6491?hideProgress=true",
"httpVerb": "PUT",
"postData": {
"committed": "true",
}
}
]
}
response = requests.post('localhost:8080/.../bulk', headers=headers, json=json_data)

the header that I provided works fine.
```

this is the error that I am getting.

```
{u'count': 2, u'successCount': 0, u'data': [{u'request': {u'uri': u'http://shortterm-2075.rg5.emdevinfrabom.oraclevcn.com:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/6491/attributes', u'postData': u'[{&quot;attributeDefinitionId&quot;:1,&quot;values&quot;:[{&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;High&quot;}]},{&quot;attributeDefinitionId&quot;:&quot;5307&quot;,&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;DevPhase&quot;,&quot;values&quot;:[{&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;Active&quot;}]},{&quot;attributeDefinitionId&quot;:&quot;5319&quot;,&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;Accessibility&quot;,&quot;values&quot;:[{&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;externalpublicnetwork&quot;}]},{&quot;attributeDefinitionId&quot;:&quot;5312&quot;,&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;DevStrategy&quot;,&quot;values&quot;:[{&quot;guid&quot;:&quot;Internal&quot;}]}]', u'httpVerb': u'PUT'}, u'responses': [{u'body': {u'errorCode': -12300, u'message': u'Missing meta data definitions.', u'responseCode': 400}, u'headers': {}, u'requestUrl': u'http://localhost:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/6491/attributes'}]}, {u'request': {u'uri': u'shortterm-2075.rg5.emdevinfrabom.oraclevcn.com:8080/.../6491, u'postData': u'{&quot;committed&quot;:&quot;true&quot;}', u'httpVerb': u'PUT'}, u'responses': [{u'body': {u'errorCode': -12301, u'message': u'A required application attribute definition is missing a value: Development Phase.', u'responseCode': 400}, u'headers': {}, u'requestUrl': u'http://localhost:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/6491?hideProgress=true'}]}], u'responseCode': 200}
```

this is the error while committing "`A required application attribute definition is missing a value: Development Phase`" and this one while posting to its attributes `A required application attribute definition is missing a value: Development Phase.', u'responseCode': 400`

I went through many community forums and could not find any related solution.
Can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today as I purposely test which setting is necessary. You can try to `call API` separately instead of `bulk update`.

After I called `https://{{YourSscUrl}}/v1/projectVersions` and created the SSC version, I made another 2 API calls below:

1. `https://{{YourSscUrl}}/v1/projectVersions/{{YourNewCreatedProjectVersionID}}/attributes`
2. `https://{{YourSscUrl}}/v1/projectVersions/{{YourNewCreatedProjectVersionID}}?hideProgress=true`

Then I called following API as well, but it doesn't affect the error.

`https://{{YourSscUrl}}/v1/projectVersions/{{YourNewCreatedProjectVersionID}}/responsibilities`

Comment: I get the same error even after making separate api calls

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me with :

```
{
   "requests":[
      {
         "uri":"http://localhost:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/[ID]/attributes",
         "httpVerb":"PUT",
         "postData":[
            {
               "attributeDefinitionId":5,
               "values":[
                  {
                     "guid":"Active"
                  }
               ],
               "value":null
            },
            {
               "attributeDefinitionId":1,
               "values":[
                  {
                     "guid":"High"
                  }
               ],
               "value":null
            },
            {
               "attributeDefinitionId":6,
               "values":[
                  {
                     "guid":"Customized"
                  }
               ],
               "value":null
            },
            {
               "attributeDefinitionId":7,
               "values":[
                  {
                     "guid":"consoleaccess"
                  }
               ],
               "value":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "uri":"http://localhost:8080/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions/[ID]?hideProgress=true",
         "httpVerb":"PUT",
         "postData":{
            "committed":true
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for any existing application in fortify via rest api

curl -X POST 'https://yourfortifysscurl/ssc/api/v1/projectVersions' --header 'accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: FortifyToken MmRjODVjZjctOWE2Zi00NGQxLWFkZTAtZmE2ZjUxZmZiYmU1' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -o response.json

Look for any application that is already created in fortify (which has development phase, strategy set already and able to scan) and search for that application name in the above obtained response.json

2. Check for the attributedefinitiodId, projectdefinitionId, id, guid(development phase/strategy etc) which are showing in above json response.
3. Use the above details, create the payload and perform the rest api call for your new application you are trying to create.

You can follow - the rest api syntax and values to be included in PAYLOAD at https://yourfortifysscurl/ssc/html/docs/api-reference/index.jsp